# How to detect steps and squats from accelerometer or magnetometer or gyroscope

Tags: java, c++, accelerometer, sensors, mpu

I am working on mpu9150 sensors data (3 axial acceleration, 3 axial magnetic field and 3 axial gyroscope data). I have raw data in my database called, influxDB. I want to detect (monitor) steps and squats from those raw data using java or c++. I did not find any proper way to implement it. Can you please suggest me any library to do it?

Thank you

Comment: This question is too broad, but if you intend to read from the database in Java, you are going to need to use JDBC.  After this, you will need more code to massage the data for your analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, i can read data using simple connection with my database. But, for motion detection like steps and squats i need to develop proper algorithms. so may be using any library i can do it.

Comment: Please narrow down your question then if this is the area where you have some doubts.

Comment: I just want to know the proper way for motion detection.